# Class not found exception in java?

Tags: java

I have two classes in the same package(users).

the first class:

```
package users;

public class Account{
  public String username;
  public String password;
}
```

the second class:

```
package users;

public class employee{

  public void login() {
    Account a = new Account();
    a.username = "MHM";
    a.password = "15234785";
    System.out.println("Username: " + a.username);
    System.out.println("Password: " + a.password);
  }
}
```

In the main page when i called the method(login):

it says to me: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Account

```
  package users;

  public class Main{

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
      employee e = new employee();
      e.login();  
    }
  }
```

what is the fix for this error?

note: these classes were written in the default package then i create package users then move them into the new package.... before moving them in the new package they were working good but after moving the problem is occurs.

Comment: I voted to close because this is "a simple typographical error. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per see this,

First of all keep in mind that,
In one/single package maximum 1-class should be public, more than 1-class as a public modifier not possible.

As i seen you code, it seems that you forget Data-type,

make it correct like,

```
package users;


class Account{
  public String username;
  public String password;
}

class employee{

  public void login() {
    Account a = new Account();
    a.username = "MHM";
    a.password = "15234785";
    System.out.println("Username: " + a.username);
    System.out.println("Password: " + a.password);
  }
}

public class MyMainClass{
   public static void main(String [] args){
    // block of code... 
  }
}
```

> If you want more classes a public modifier then do it by make
>   individual package for all public class.

**EDITED**

```
  package users;

    class Account{
          public String username;
          public String password;
        }

    class employee{

          public void login() {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.username = "MHM";
            a.password = "15234785";
            System.out.println("Username: " + a.username);
            System.out.println("Password: " + a.password);
          }
        }


    public class MyMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            employee e = new employee();
            e.login();  
        }

    }

 /*
Output : 
---------------
Username: MHM
Password: 15234785

*/
```

Comment: I forget to add data type when posting code in the question so post is edited but in the real file on my netbeans.. the data type is written. and the same problem exists.

Comment: one more thing you need to update is remove 'public'  access modifier which is not application that into one source file more than one class as a public not possible. only the class which has main method mark them public. leave other as a default modifier

Comment: i can told you something, these classes were written in the default package then i create package users then move them into the new package.... before moving them in the new package they were working good but after moving the problem is occurs.

Comment: can you post correct code, with correct package details , i will provide you correct solution

Comment: read my post again, there is no other details i can provide. @vishalgajera

Comment: @MHM please remove public identifier first or remove package statement from it. because at a time all class public with same package not possible. it's create confusion for me. if possible then edit it correctly.

Comment: i removed all public identifiers and make them default.... also the same problem exists.

Comment: look, i tried to search google about this error.... found some results that say: "When you get error "classnotfoundexception class_name" so this means that your program cannot found the path for this class so it says not found" .... what is you opinion about this ??

Comment: @MHM please refer my 'EDITED' of my answer. it's correctly works. please copy paste it into your system and run again. it's work perfectly.

Comment: NO, STILL NOT WORKING. as i mentioned in my post ... i said that when using default package the code is working but when putting the code into different package the code is not working.

Comment: iam sorry sir for wasting your time... thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

Your Account class is not defined properly. You forgot to add the types of the variables "username" and "password". It should probably be:

```
public class Account{
public String username;
public String password;
}
```

(Not to mention that public global variables are never a good thing to choose (instead use getters and setters) - but that's a different topic here :) )

Comment: sorry, i forget to add String when posting code. i write String in my file in NetBeans ..... its the same problem exists.

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Account

Your `Account` class is not compilable.Change your Account class like this

```
public class Account{
public String username;
public String password;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tested your code.There is no other issue except this.Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Account` class will not compile because `username` and `password` need the object type. i.e, `String`.

```
public class Account{
  public String username;
  public String password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this all it's ok:

```
 public class Account{
   public String username;
   public String  password;
}
```

The variables should be have a type

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing `ClassNotFoundException` because your `Account` class has not been compiled . Hence `.class` file has not been generated.

To make the compilation successful `Account` class as below :

```
public class Account{
public String username;
public String password;
}
```